# I have problems with my page margin. Width is not working

Tags: html, css

I was designing a home page but I dealt with :

[image]

and something like this in footer part...

It never happened to me before :(

here you can find all stylesheets and html docs

```css
/* Style For All Page*/
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}
.mainclss{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.dateclss{
    background-color: #212;
    height: 25px;
    color: bisque;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.logoclss{
    background-color: inherit;
    border-bottom: 2px #f6f6f6 inset;
    margin: auto 0px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.logoclss img{
    width: 300px;
}
.navmenueclss ul{
    margin:  0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navmenueclss ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px 15px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    font-size: large;
}
.navmenueclss ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff5e6;
}
.navmenueclss{
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #212121;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
/*just home page style*/
.branchclss{
    border-top: 3px #f6f6f6 solid;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px #f6f6f6 inset;
}
.singlebranchclss{
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px 30px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.singlebranchclss:hover{
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button:hover{
    border: none;
}
.footerclss{
    background-color: #212121;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.footerclss ul{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.footerclss ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px 10px;
}
.footerclss ul li a img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<style>
/* Style For All Page*/
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}
.mainclss{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.dateclss{
    background-color: #212;
    height: 25px;
    color: bisque;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.logoclss{
    background-color: inherit;
    border-bottom: 2px #f6f6f6 inset;
    margin: auto 0px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.logoclss img{
    width: 300px;
}
.navmenueclss ul{
    margin:  0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navmenueclss ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px 15px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    font-size: large;
}
.navmenueclss ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff5e6;
}
.navmenueclss{
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #212121;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
/*just home page style*/
.branchclss{
    border-top: 3px #f6f6f6 solid;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px #f6f6f6 inset;
}
.singlebranchclss{
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px 30px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.singlebranchclss:hover{
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button:hover{
    border: none;
}
.footerclss{
    background-color: #212121;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.footerclss ul{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.footerclss ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px 10px;
}
.footerclss ul li a img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

<style/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/home.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png"/>
    <title>آریا زی</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainclss">
        <div class="dateclss">
            date will appear here....
        </div>
        <div class="logoclss">
            <img src="img/navlogo.png" alt="sitelogo">
        </div>
        <div class="navmenueclss">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">
                    خانه
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    دوخت
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    بافت
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    چرم
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    تماس با ما
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="branchclss">
            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/dooxtport.png" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ورود
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/charmport.jpg" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ورود
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/baftport.png" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ورود
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="footerclss">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/insta1.png" alt="insta"/></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/twitter1.png" alt="twitter"/></a> </li>
                    <li><a><img src="img/tel1.png" alt="tele"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose they end out of the screen and allow an horizontal scroll!!

Comment: It seems like all of your <div> tags have a left padding.
Have you checked for any css affecting those div?

Comment: Also if you can show some code, if you don't your question will recive downvotes cause it's hard to understand what you need

Comment: I updated the code, try my code

Answer (score 0):

There were some padding values causing this problem.
Using a padding value on a `<div>` makes it move from its position.

Try changing the code to

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/home.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png"/>
    <title>???? ??</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainclss">
        <div class="dateclss">
            date will appear here....
        </div>
        <div class="logoclss">
            <img src="img/navlogo.png" alt="sitelogo">
        </div>
        <div class="navmenueclss">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ????
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ????
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ????
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ???
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ???? ?? ??
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="branchclss">
            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/dooxtport.png" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ????
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/charmport.jpg" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ????
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/baftport.png" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ????
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="footerclss">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/insta1.png" alt="insta"/></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/twitter1.png" alt="twitter"/></a> </li>
                    <li><a><img src="img/tel1.png" alt="tele"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
/* Style For All Page*/
body{
    margin: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}
.mainclss{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.dateclss{
    background-color: #212;
    height: 25px;
    color: bisque;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}
.logoclss{
    background-color: inherit;
    border-bottom: 2px #f6f6f6 inset;
    margin: auto 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navmenueclss ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px 15px;
    font-size: large;
}
.navmenueclss ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff5e6;
}
.navmenueclss{
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #212121;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
/*just home page style*/
.branchclss{
    border-top: 3px #f6f6f6 solid;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px #f6f6f6 inset;
}
.singlebranchclss{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px 30px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.singlebranchclss:hover{
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button:hover{
    border: none;
}
.footerclss{
    background-color: #212121;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.footerclss ul{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.footerclss ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px 10px;
}
.footerclss ul li a img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

<style/>
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/home.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png"/>
    <title>???? ??</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainclss">
        <div class="dateclss">
            date will appear here....
        </div>
        <div class="logoclss">
            <img src="img/navlogo.png" alt="sitelogo">
        </div>
        <div class="navmenueclss">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ????
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ????
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ????
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ???
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    ???? ?? ??
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="branchclss">
            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/dooxtport.png" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ????
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/charmport.jpg" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ????
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="singlebranchclss">
                <img src="img/baftport.png" alt="Dookht portal">
                <a href="#">
                    <button about="interanc">
                        ????
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="footerclss">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/insta1.png" alt="insta"/></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/twitter1.png" alt="twitter"/></a> </li>
                    <li><a><img src="img/tel1.png" alt="tele"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
/* Style For All Page*/
body{
    margin: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}
.mainclss{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.dateclss{
    background-color: #212;
    height: 25px;
    color: bisque;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}
.logoclss{
    background-color: inherit;
    border-bottom: 2px #f6f6f6 inset;
    margin: auto 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navmenueclss ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px 15px;
    font-size: large;
}
.navmenueclss ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff5e6;
}
.navmenueclss{
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #212121;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
/*just home page style*/
.branchclss{
    border-top: 3px #f6f6f6 solid;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px #f6f6f6 inset;
}
.singlebranchclss{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px 30px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.singlebranchclss:hover{
    border: 2px #e2e2e2 ridge;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.branchclss .singlebranchclss button:hover{
    border: none;
}
.footerclss{
    background-color: #212121;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.footerclss ul{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.footerclss ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px 10px;
}
.footerclss ul li a img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

<style/>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not helpful. What did you change? How did it solve the problem? What was the OP doing wrong?

Comment: As I said in a previous comment the code had usless "padding" values in it that just caused visual errors

Comment: @Claire I edited the answer to make it more clear :)

Answer (score -1):

You just have to apply only box-sizing css in your css section to resolve this issue.

```
*,
  *::after,
  *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```